# NavBar not loading from a local file in chrome

Tags: jquery, html

I wanted a navbar for my website where I could edit a single file, and it would change it on all the pages, so I went with this solution that I found on the internet.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

inside "head" tag, and...

```
<!--Navigation bar-->
<div id="nav-placeholder">

</div>

<script>
$(function(){
  $("#nav-placeholder").load("nav.html");
});
</script>
<!--end of Navigation bar-->
```

inside the "body" tag.

nav.html has a "style" tag, and a "header" tag with "svg" tag inside. I am using Dreamweaver, and it works fine when I look at a live preview on chrome, but when I go and open that HTML file directly with chrome, the nav-bar just doesn't load. When I open the file directly in Edge however, it workes perfectly, the navbar appears.

What is going on, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Any errors in chrome console?

Comment: I think, when you open the html file directly, the url is the local file path. But when you open from Edge,url will be an http url.

Comment: @A A Nope, they are both file URLs

Comment: @Roland Ruul No errors